# Update Javascript object with code from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, get

I have a function to create a new object 'dialogBox' and then perform an an AJAX request and add/remove buttons from it. The function works fine as part of my main HTML page using the following code:

```
var dialog1 = new dialogBox(500, 250, "Add Note","dialog_add_note.php?job_id=" + jobdetails[1]);
dialog1.addButton("Save","Right");
```

I have numerous (20+) dialog boxes, and therefore want update the content of the buttons after the box has been initialised.

I perform an AJAX request which updates the HTML within the dialog box. The following script is returned as part of this request:

```
dialog1.addButton("Save","Right");
```

I get an error stating that dialog1 is now undefined.

Is there a way which I can continue to update the object using javascript code which has been passed by the AJAX request? I had done this prevously without using objects, but it was becoming unmanageable.

Thanks in advance

---

The AJAX request is performed when the object is initialised. See function below:

```
function dialogBox(w, h, title, link) {

this.w=w;
this.h=h;
this.title=title;
this.link=link;

//Strip spaces from title to form ID
var id = 'dialog_' + title.replace(" ","_");

//Add dialog box div
$( "body" ).append( "<div id='" + id + "' title='" + title + "'></div>");

//Create dialog box
$( '#' + id ).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: h,
    width: w,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {
            $('#' + id).remove();
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $('#' + id).remove();
    }
});

//Set buttonSet and remove all buttons
this.buttonSet = $('#' + id).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonset');
this.buttonSet.empty();

//Loading icon
$('#' + id).html("<div style='text-align:center;'><br><img src='../images/ajaxloader.gif' alt='Loading...'></div>");

//Set initial content of dialog box
$.get('ajax/' + link, function(data) {
        $('#' + id).html(data);
});

//Function to update content of dialog box
this.update=update;
function update(link) {
    $.get('ajax/' + link, function(data) {
            $('#' + id).html(data);
    });
}

//Clear button
this.clearButton = clearButton
function clearButton(name) {
    var tempName = name.replace(" ","_");
    $('#' + id + '_button_' + tempName).remove();
}

//Clear buttons
this.clearButtons = clearButtons
function clearButtons() {
    this.buttonSet.empty(); 
}

//Add Button
this.addButton = addButton
function addButton(name, position) {
    var tempName = name.replace(" ","_");
    newButton = $("<button id='" + tempName + "' style='float:" + position + ";'>" + name + "</button>");
    newButton.button();
    this.buttonSet.append(newButton);
}

//Close Dialog
this.close=close
function close() {
    $('#' + id).remove();
}
```

}

Comment: So where are you initializing your dialog1? Is your AJAX call at the same place where your dialog1 is present? Is dialog1 object a globally available object (to your complete html page)?

Comment: dialog1 is initialised on a click event. This click event is defined within a function 'context_menu' which is called when the main page is initialised.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt about global variables. I've fixed the issue by using window.dialog1 to ensure that it's defined globally.